# WPF with an Asp.Net MVC Background

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wpf

As an Asp.Net MVC developer, what is the best starting point to dive into WPF?

Answer (score 1):

WPF is a totally different technology used for a different purpose. You're writing desktop applications rather than web applications.

While there is some cross over in terms of design patterns and both use C# (or VB.NET) as the "code behind", they each need their own approach.

Your best bet is to read and work through some WPF tutorials and then decide on a fairly simple application to write from scratch. Get that working and you'll have a reasonable grounding in the technology.

Answer (score 1):

WPF is a platform for developing Windows Application , while ASP.NET MVC is a platform for developing Web Applications.
If you are into Web apps development, and you want to learning something similar to WPF, you can go for **Silverlight.**

Silverlight is Rich Internet Application development **(RIA)** platform that can be used to develop interative web apps. Silverlight is also capable of running on desktop as Out of Browser Application.

I suggested Silverlight because, **Silverlight** & **WPF** both share a markup language called **XAML** to a great extent. Once you are familiar with XAML, you can slowly start with WPF.

WPF consists of wide range of new terminologies and techniques such as :

- Routed Events
- Data Binding
- Commands
- Styles and Templates

Some of these are present in Silverlight while some are yet to be introduced in future versions Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a framework that helps you apply some 'best practices' in WPF/Silverlight development (similar to MVC helping you in the ASP.Net world), you may want to have a look at [caliburn](http://caliburn.codeplex.com) and/or [prism (aka. CompositeWPF)](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com). However, as others have stated, it's probably a good idea to learn some of the basics of WPF first.